# How to get the logged in Windows user/browser user when the IIS user running the app is different?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

The web app I'm working on is running on an IIS server with a dedicated user assigned in the ApplicationPool. However to access some data stored in the database I need to get the SID of the currently-logged in Windows user. Since the app is running on the IIS-assigned user, any operation that tries to get the SID normally keeps returning the same SID no matter who opens the app. Is there any way to acquire information about the user who is either running the browser the app is displayed in or currently logged in?

My first idea was to add Windows authentication to the web app and get their data from there but unfortunately that goes against the project requirements.

Comment: `My first idea was to add Windows authentication to the web app` ....this is exactly what you need to do. (Or if you have AAD, you could potentially use OAuth. Beyond that there is no other alternative.). `that goes against the project requirements`...you're going to have to do some negotiating then. I guess it will depend how vital this functionality is, what the reasons are for not wanting windows auth enabled, and how flexible whoever made this rule is.

Comment: The problem is the Windows Authentication logon prompt as it adds "unnecessary steps for the user" - and as far as I know there is no way to have WinAuth and disable the logon prompt without always forcing the user to open it with Internet Explorer and set it up manually.

Comment: If the user is using a browser which supports integrated authentication directly (IE and Edge, and also Chrome can be configured to support it) then within a windows domain network they won't even see that prompt anyway. if you're seeing the prompt in IE or Edge then something in your domain setup isn't quite right - that's assuming this is an intranet application deployed within a windows AD domain, where users are logged into the same domain (or a related, trusted domain) as the IIS server?

Comment: P.S. I dispute the `unnecessary` in `unnecessary steps for the user` ...if the application needs to know the user's identity in order to work correctly, then then capturing the user's identity is clearly going to be a "necessary" step. Although as I've mentioned above you should be able to avoid the manual intervention aspect in most cases.